# Error in SAPUI5 routing / binding with 1.18 SDK example: SplitApp

Tags: sapui5

When testing the SplitApp demo app provided with the 1.18.5 SAPUI5 SDK there seems to be a conflict between the routing and model binding. If you navigate to a detail page and then refresh the browser window the data binding fails. This would be the same as if you bookmarked the app on a specific view.

Just wondering if anyone knows why this is? Is it a conflict with routing and data binding? My debugging is not showing anything up yet only that the model is empty when the detail view loads.

This app uses the new Component-based router where you define your routes in the component metadata.

I've also written a small test app here [js1972/test · GitHub (branch "routes")](https://github.com/js1972/test/tree/routes) which does similar and has the same issue.

Comment: I installed your code and got the same issue, swapped the fake sinon service for http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/ and both refresh and bookmarking works well

Comment: Hi John, thats an interesting finding. I've just done the same and it does work when using the remote northwind service. There is a delay where I initially see no_data, then it populates (async and all that). So looks like an issue with local data in the Model only. The UI5 SDK demo apps use local data sources so they fail as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following bookmark works with the fake service
../test-routes/#/detail/Categories(2)

../test-routes/#/detail/Categories(3)
doesnt

request.onSend in ODataModelFakeService.js doesnt cater for all scenarios

an alternative maybe to use sap.ui.core.util.MockServer with a cutdown metadata.xml and json files for the Category and Product entities

Comment: Thanks john. Its one of those chicken and the egg scenarios. As per our previous investigations I have issue with Northwind working on my windows PC so needed the mock service. Now the combo of routing and binding doesn't work with the mock service but it does the real one.

Comment: There is still a bug in there somewhere - look at all the SDK provided demo apps that use routing or history - they all fail with the same issue.

Comment: tried MockServer with Northwind mock service there is an issue getting the Product Count getting a NaN, products expands working though

Comment: this app works https://openui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/core/samples/routing/mobile/index.html#/9 others dont

Comment: I"m accepting your answer here - to sum up - Northwind is just a dodgy service. It seems to have DNS issues and won't work properly from my windows PC yet is fine on a Mac. If you use the mock odata service provided by UI5 which replicates the Northwind service it doesn't handle all functions as you've mentioned so is not 100% either. So I just built my own json dataset for testing and its now 100% working fine.

Comment: For anyone that is interested - here is my test UI5 Routing app that correct works with bookmarking: https://github.com/js1972/test_ui5_routing

Comment: This can come in handy as well: http://metasapiens.com/sesame/data-browser/preview/ - an online oData service viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue and just want to share my findings and solution:

The detail view waits until the list in the master view is loaded. If the service you are using is quite slow the list has already finsihed loading, but the model has not finished loading and thus the detail view returns an error.
To fix this I've attached an "requestCompleted"-event to the model and created a jQuery.Deferred object for the model.
The master then waits for the resolve of the model.

```html
oModel.attachEvent("requestCompleted", 
    function() {
       this.oModelFinishedDeferred.resolve();
       this.getEventBus().publish("Model",
       "ModelFinished");}
   , this);
```